# Can the TTS Extended library be installed on the Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk, text-to-speech

Can the TTS Extended library be installed on the Android Emulator?

If the answer is positive, how do I accomplish that?

Comment: If you can find the APK you can just install it using ADB.

Comment: @blindstuff I found this URL http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-google-tts-iDB.aspx but nowhere could I find the APK there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, that proved easier than I thought. Just did it via:

http://www.appbrain.com/app/text-to-speech-extended/com.google.tts

However, it should be noted that "TTS Extended" is no longer needed for Android 2.2 and up.